# what is class score map?

Tags: deep-learning, vgg-net

I was going through [vggnet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf) paper and i came across the testing phase of vggnet.

During the testing phase, test image goes through the vggnet and  a class score map is obtained. This class score map is spatially averaged to produce a fixed size vector.

I have googled class score map, but then i couldn't find any relevant results. I wish to know what is the role of class score map.

Any hint would be greatly helpful. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you train an image recognition model, you train it for a specific image size (and resolution), let's say n_dims = `[256, 256]`. Now, in the prediction phase, you have images of different sizes (with respect to pixels), e.g. `[1024, 1024]`. You extract patches (you can resize the image first by lowering the resolution) and hover over the image patches with your model, and for each patch, you obtain a prediction for all classes (in a patch, more than one of the objects might be present), which you have to average somehow for the whole image at the end.

See [OverFeat: Integrated Recognition, Localization and Detection using Convolutional Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6229).

> Instead, we explore the entire image by densely running the network at each location and at multiple
>   scales. While the sliding window approach may be computationally prohibitive for certain types
>   of model, it is inherently efficient in the case of ConvNets (see section 3.5). This approach yields
>   significantly more views for voting, which increases robustness while remaining efficient. The result
>   of convolving a ConvNet on an image of arbitrary size is a spatial map of C-dimensional vectors at
>   each scale.

Comment: you are telling me C-dimensional vector is the class score map.